# How to collect real-time data from dynamic JS websites using Python Scrapy+Splash?

Tags: scrapy-splash

I am using Scrapy-Splash to scrape real-time data from JavaScript websites. I am using Docker to run Splash. The Spider works completely fine, and I'm getting the required data from the website. However, the Spider crawls once and finishes the process, so I get the data of a particular time. I want to continuously collect the data and store it in a database(i.e MySQL) since the data is updated every second. The crawl needs to be continued and show the data in real-time using plotting libraries(i.e Matplotlib, Plotly). Is there any way to keep the Spider running as the Splash renders the updated data(I'm not sure if Splash updates the data like a normal browser)? Here's my code,

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapy.http import Request

class MandalaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mandala'

    def start_requests(self):
        link="website link"
        yield SplashRequest(url=link, callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self,response):
        products=response.css('a.abhead::text').getall()
        nub=[]
        for prod in products:
            prod=prod.strip()
            prod=prod.split()
            nub.extend(prod)
        data=pd.DataFrame({
            'Name' : nub[0:len(nub):4],
            'Price' : nub[1:len(nub):4],
            'Change' : nub[2:len(nub):4],
            'Change_percent' : nub[3:len(nub)+1:4],
        })
        # For single data monitoring
        sub=[]
        sub=sub.extend(data.iloc[3,1])
        yield sub

        yield Request(response.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

I am completely a newbie in web scraping, so any additional information is greatly appreciated. I have searched other posts from this website but unfortunately couldn't get the solid info that I needed. This type of problem is solved usually using Selenium and BeautifulSoup. But I wanted to use Scrapy.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to continuously collect data from the website, you can just include your code into infinite loop?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think you are recommending the `while` loop if I'm not wrong. But I would like to avoid it. I would personally run crawling using `if` and `for` for a given timeframe. So, is there any way to make continuous requests to the website without ending the crawling process? A simple code demonstration would be greatly appreciated. Thanks...